# Is there a way to extract domains from a .dll file?

Tags: windows, browser, dll, telemetry, data-mining

I'm trying to extract domains from tracking browsers such as Opera or Maxthon so I can block them in my hosts file, like [this redditor did with Edge](https://www.reddit.com/r/edge/comments/rvumg1/unmicrosofted_edge_block_tracking_in_microsoft/).

I tried to do the same using [this guide](https://suip.biz/?act=rabin2), but didn't see any domains in the output. Anything I can try? I don't want to have to ditch software just because of spyware, if it's possible to block the tracking domains instead.

Comment: You can switch to Firefox, which is a better browser than Opera and Maxthon. Opera and Maxthon get frequent updates, so blocking isn't a set it and forget it scenario. You can also look into getting something like a pi-hole. Keep track of where the browser phones home and then block it.

Comment: What this redditor did with Edge was to block all functionality of it except browsing, including updates. This is really excessive and not to be followed.

Comment: It's possible, yes, but these are closed source browsers and the methods of reading their compiled code is not published. There are better ways to do what you want, ways already suggested in the other comments.